# Java - How to convert this string to date?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am receiving this from the server and I don´t understand what the T and Z means, `2012-08-24T09:59:59Z` What's the correct SimpleDateFormat pattern to convert this string to a Date object?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml) link will serve you as a starting point.

Comment: Duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) Standard. You may use

`SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");`

to convert this.

Comment: Thanks! It's the first time I had to work with this type of date.

Comment: Not if the timezone differs from "Z".

Comment: In my case Timezone will always be Z

Answer (score 2):

```
RSS 2.0 format string EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z   
Example: Tue, 28 Aug 2012 06:55:11 EDT

Atom (ISO 8601) format string  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz
Example:2012-08-28T06:55:11EDT

try {
            String str_date = "2012-08-24T09:59:59Z";
            DateFormat formatter;
            Date date;
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
            System.out.println("Today is " + date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Z stands for Zulu (UTC) and this is the [dateTime.tz](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MicrosyntaxDescriptions#datetime-tz) format ([ISO-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)). So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

There is an example here: [example](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2004-09-dates)

Answer (score 2):

This is the ISO datetime format, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC), T is the time separator and Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset.

There is a very similar, if not identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date), see it to know how to convert this string to a Java DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2012-08-24T09:59:59Z";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
        DateTime dt = parser.parseDateTime(text);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime();
        System.out.println(formatter.print(dt));
    }
}
```

or simply check that link
[str to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393847/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-from-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmsssssz-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the excellent [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library to convert a String as a Date:

```
LocalDate myDate = new LocalDate("2012-08-28") // the constructor need an Object but is internally able to parse a String.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// First parse string in pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" to date object.

String dateString1 = "2012-08-24T09:59:59Z";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(dateString1);

// Then format date object to string in pattern "MM/dd/yy 'at' h:mma".
String dateString2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy 'at' h:mma").format(date);
System.out.println(dateString2); // 08/24/12 at 09:59AM
```

I think this might be useful to you.