# java.text.Parse Exception : Unparseable Date

Tags: java, parsing, date, iso8601

**I have the following code:**

```
  String ModifiedDate = "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z" ;  
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
  Date ModDate = sdf.parse(ModifiedDate);
```

I am getting the following exception even though my date format is fine...

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
```

Comment: Try single quote the 'Z'  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

Comment: Do you want to use ISODateTimeFormat (which is in joda)?  Might be better for that ISO8601 standard. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393847/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-from-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmsssssz-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Z` pattern latter indicates an RFC 822 time zone. Your string

```
String ModifiedDate = "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z" ;
```

does not contain such a time zone. It contains a `Z` literally.

You'll want a date pattern, that similarly to the literal `T`, has a literal `Z`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

If you meant for `Z` to indicate Zulu time, add that as a timezone when constructing the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Zulu"));;
```

Comment: I will add change the `ModifiedDate` to take a time zone difference such as '2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700' [SampleDateFormat Examples section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @gtgaxiola Absolutely, if OP can change their input string, it might be easier to do that.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

The [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html), released with Java-8 in March 2014, supplanted the legacy date-time API (the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`). Since then, it is strongly recommended to stop using the error-prone legacy API and switch to `java.time` API.

**Solution using `java.time` API**: `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z`).

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strModifiedDate = "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // It can also be directly parsed into a ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // or even into an OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1993-06-08T18:27:02Z
1993-06-08T18:27:02Z
1993-06-08T18:27:02Z
```

If for any reason, you need `java.util.Date` instance, you can get it as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Just for the sake of completeness:

Here is the solution using the legacy date-time API. First of all, note that ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573). `'Z'` is just a character literal whereas `Z` is the timezone designator for zero-timezone offset (or UTC). So, never use `'Z'` in the date-time formatting/parsing pattern; otherwise, it will be interpreted merely as a literal character, and not as a timezone designator.

The correct letter to be used in the pattern for timezone offset is `X`.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String strModifiedDate = "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        Date modifiedDate = sdf.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(modifiedDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24192471/642706) is correct. The `Z` means Zulu time, a zero offset from UTC (+00:00). In other words, not adjusted to any time zone.

## Joda-Time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library make this work much easier, as does the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29).

The format you are using is defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Joda-Time and java.time both parse & generate ISO 8601 strings by default.

A DateTime in Joda-Time knows its own assigned time zone. So as part of the process of parsing, specify a time zone to adjust.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z", timeZone );
String output = dateTime.toString();
```

You can keep the DateTime object in [Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) if desired.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "1993-06-08T18:27:02.000Z", DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

When required by other classes, you can generate a java.util.Date object.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```