# How to convert String date to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, string, date

I have a date as a String format like this -

```
String testDate = "2014-11-5T19:11:27";
```

Now I need to convert above String date to `java.util.Date` format. I was trying below code but it is not able to recognize `T` in it.

```
String testDate = "2014-11-5T19:11:27";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a timestamp from yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:SSSZ format to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS format? From ISO8601 to UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393847/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-from-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmsssssz-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` needs to be enclosed in quotes since it isnt used to match a date element in the `DateFormat` pattern

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @AKIWEB It's a standard used for timestamps that avoids having spaces in them, which in many programming context would indicate field separation. With `T` it's easier to parse text files that contain time stamps.