# How to set date of proper format in android

Tags: android

Is there any other way to get custom date in android except that java date picker

Comment: have you ever seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393847/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-from-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmsssssz-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Hi Milad sorry for late reply . I got the answer .I used java code for getting date .After that i simply split the string according to our requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you're trying to parse a date that doesn't match the pattern you choose. You should have a look at the simple date documentation to see which pattern you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

This link might help too: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html